# How to remove press esc to exit full screen in firefox and chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I used this JavaScript code to full screen the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="border:1px solid red;height:100px;width:100px;background-color:red;" onclick="requestFullScreen(document.body)"></div>
    <div style="border:1px solid red;height:100px;width:100px;background-color:blue;" onclick="exitFullScreen(document.body)"></div>

    <script>
        function requestFullScreen(element) {
            // Supports most browsers and their versions.
            var requestMethod = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.msRequestFullscreen;

            if (requestMethod) { // Native full screen.
                requestMethod.call(element);
            } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") { // Older IE.
                var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                if (wscript !== null) {
                    wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
                }
            }
        }

    </script>

    <script>
        function exitFullScreen() {
            if (document.exitFullscreen) {
                document.exitFullscreen();
            }
            else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
                document.msExitFullscreen();
            }
            else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                document.mozCancelFullScreen();
            }
            else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
                document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but it show "press esc to exit full screen" in full screen mode.
How to remove  "press esc to exit full screen" in firefox and chrome?

Comment: You can't. It's a security feature designed to not let malicious sites mislead or trap a user - it's not something you can remove.

Answer (score 64):

**It's super easy in Firefox:**

1. In the URL bar enter `about:config`
2. Agree to the security risks
3. Search for the entry `browser.fullscreen.exit_on_escape`
4. Double click on `true` to change it to `false`
5. You're done! Enjoy :-)

Comment: This is amazing! Wish something like this would exist for Chrome/Safari

Comment: I think this is old information, there is now only one option in browser.fullscreen. Instead, this worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1099783/260284

Namely, set full-screen-api.warning.timeout to 0 and full-screen-api.warning.delay to -1

Comment: Works in Firefox 115.0.2 and Firefox Developer Edition 116.0b8 on Mac OS so at least on Mac OS it's not old information.

Comment: This is helpful information, but not relevant to the question. Am I taking crazy pills?

Answer (score -1):

You can't. It's a security feature designed to not let malicious sites mislead or trap a user - it's not something you can remove.